# Removing duplicates on two sheets in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a macro that will look at a list on sheet 2 and look for the same value on sheet 1. If/when it finds it, it would delete the row on sheet 1. Then it would end at the bottem of sheet 2. Any advice would help, thank you!

Comment: I presume this is for Excel.  Please update the title and/or the tag to reflect what platform you're working with.

Comment: It is excel, my apologies,  I am newer to this stuff I will right now.

Comment: Not a problem and good luck!

Comment: A good starting point is recording a macro and look at its source code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to loop through the values on sheet 2. On each value, check if it exists on sheet 1, and if so, delete that row.

The key is in how you structure your loop, and how you plan for the unexpected. How does your code handle if the same value is listed more than once on sheet 1? What if there are blank spots in sheet 1?

My advice is to use a built-in function such as the `.Find` method. This can skip over unexpected spaces, and it can easily be called multiple times. More info on this and other methods is found by pressing **F1** in VBA editor, or you can look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805535489990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=3a7d3e7e%2Da4f5%2D491f%2Db2e8%2D6612e0ebb357).

As has been pointed out [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10717999#10717999), avoiding using `.Select` is also good practice.

---

To get you started, here is an outline of what's possible, looking at information in Sheet2 rows 1 through 3, and replacing those values in Sheet1 rows 1 through 10:

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()

'look at sheet2, A1 through A3 for search values
For Each search_value In Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A3")
  'as long as there is something to delete...
  Do While Not Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10"). _
  Find(search_value.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    '...delete that row
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10").Find(search_value.Value, _
    lookat:=xlWhole).EntireRow.Delete
  Loop
Next

End Sub
```